# Intro rule for "∀r>0" in Isabelle

Tags: logic, isabelle, isar

When I have a goal such as `"∀x. P x"` in Isabelle, I know that I can write

```
show "∀x. P x"
proof (rule allI)
```

However, when the goal is `"∀x>0. P x"`, I cannot do that. Is there a similar rule/method that I can use after `proof` in order to simplify my goal? I would also be interested in one for the situation where you have a goal of the form `"∃x>0. P x"`.

I'm looking for an Isar proof that uses the `proof (rule something)` style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Universal quantifier

To expand on Lars's answer: `∀x>0. P x` is just syntactic sugar for `∀x. x > 0 ⟶ P x`. As a consequence, if you want to prove a statement like this, you first have to strip away the universal quantifier with `allI` and then strip away the implication with `impI`. You can do something like this:

```
lemma "∀x>0. P x"
proof (rule allI, rule impI)
```

Or using `intro`, which is more or less the same as applying `rule` until it is not possible anymore:

```
lemma "∀x>0. P x"
proof (intro allI impI)
```

Or you can use `safe`, which eagerly applies all introduction rules that are declared as ‘safe’, such as `allI` and `impI`:

```
lemma "∀x>0. P x"
proof safe
```

In any case, your new proof state is then

```
proof (state)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀x. 0 < x ⟹ P x
```

And you can proceed like this:

```
lemma "∀x>0. P (x :: nat)"
proof safe
  fix x :: nat assume "x > 0"
  show "P x"
```

Note that I added an annotation; I didn't know what type your `P` has, so I just used `nat`. When you fix a variable in Isar and the type is not clear from the assumptions, you will get a warning that a new free type variable was introduced, which is not what you want. When you get that warning, you should add a type annotation to the `fix` like I did above.

## Existential quantifier

For an existential quantifier, `safe` will not work because the intro rule `exI` is not always safe due to technical reasons. The typical proof pattern for an `∃x>0. P x` would be something like:

```
lemma "∃x>0. P (x :: nat)"
proof -
  have "42 > (0 :: nat)" by simp
  moreover have "P 42" sorry
  ultimately show ?thesis by blast
qed
```

Or a little more explicitly:

```
lemma "∃x>0. P (x :: nat)"
proof -
  have "42 > 0 ∧ P 42" sorry
  thus ?thesis by (rule exI)
qed
```

In cases when the existential witness (i.e. the 42 in this example) does not depend on any variables that you got out of an `obtain` command, you can also do it more directly:

```
lemma "∃x>0. P (x :: nat)"
proof (intro exI conjI)
```

This leaves you with the goals `?x > 0` and `P ?x`. Note that the `?x` is a schematic variable for which you can put it anything. So you can complete the proof like this:

```
lemma "∃x>0. P (x :: nat)"
proof (intro exI conjI)
  show "42 > (0::nat)" by simp
  show "P 42" sorry
qed
```

As I said, this does *not* work if your existential witness depends on some variable that you got from `obtain` due to technical restrictions. In that case, you have to fall back to the other solution I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The following works in Isabelle2016-1-RC2:

```
lemma "∀ x>0. P x"
  apply (rule allI)
```

In general, you can also just use `apply rule`, which will select the default introduction rule. Same is true for the existential quantifier.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I was looking for an Isar proof - do you know how to adapt this for Isar?

Comment: I.e., `show "\<forall> x>0. P x"
proof (rule allI) blah show ?thesis qed'` doesn't work.

Comment: Presumably your problem is the `show ?thesis` part: That's because `?thesis` always refers to the outer proposition, not the proposition after it has been massaged with an initial proof method. You have to write it down again: `fix x show "x ..."`.