# Intro rule for ∀x∈S (Isabelle)

Tags: set, logic, isabelle

Usually when you have a goal beginning `∀x` you can write something like

```
show "∀x. Px"
proof (rule allI)
```

but this doesn't seem to work when you have something beginning `∀x∈S`. For example, I tried

```
show "∀x∈S. P x"
proof (rule allI)
```

which gives the message

```
Failed to apply initial proof method
```

This surprised me, since I thought `∀x∈S. P x` was probably syntactic sugar for `∀x. x∈S --> P x`, in which case it should work.

This is similar to a question I previously asked

[Intro rule for "∀r>0" in Isabelle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746318/intro-rule-for-%E2%88%80r0-in-isabelle)

but I think that this time the answer might be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not just syntax; it is its own constant called `Ball`, and the introduction rule is called `ballI`.

If you ctrl-click onto `∀x∈A", it should take you straight to the definition, where you can see what it is called. Additionally, you can use the ‘Find theorems’ panel in Isabelle to find lemmas related to it.